# How to remove the "infinity" values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, infinity

I am trying to remove all the infinity and NaN values in the dataset by using the following code:

```
#loading data    
data_path = os.path.join('/home/~/Desktop/~/~/rf_recordings', 'WiFi_1.iqt')

nframes = 644571
iqdata = iqtools.GRData(data_path, fs = 5.12e+007, center=2.4415e+009)
iqdata.read_complete_file()
x_data = iqdata.get_spectrogram(nframes, lframes=1)

#trying to replace each inf and -inf into nan, then replace nan with mean value of x_data
df = pd.DataFrame(data = x_data)  
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)           
df = np.nan_to_num(df, nan = np.mean(x_data[1]))
print(df)
```

But the result I got shows, the original NaNs were changed to `np.mean(x_data[1])`, but changing `inf` into `nan` is not working as can see as the following:

Before

```
tensor([[[[0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00]]],


        [[[0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00]]],


        [[[0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00]]],


        ...,


        [[[       nan,        nan,        inf]]],


        [[[2.5295e-38,        nan,        nan]]],


        [[[       nan,        nan,        nan]]]])
```

After

```
tensor([[[[0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00]]],


            [[[0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00]]],


            [[[0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00]]],


            ...,


            [[[5.2155e-03, 5.2155e-03,        inf]]],


            [[[2.5295e-38, 5.2155e-03, 5.2155e-03]]],


            [[[5.2155e-03, 5.2155e-03, 5.2155e-03]]]])
```

Is there any way I can modify/improve please?

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.replace()` does not work in place by default, it returns a new dataframe.

Substitute

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

with either:

```
df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

or

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
```

with the former sometimes recommended as the latter will modify any other views of the object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried with both of your recommendations, for the first one, it makes no changes to the dataset, when I use the second one, the dataframe object becomes a nontype object and not able to change into numpy array anymore. Any idea please?